# Message error: Warning: move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload

Why am I getting this warning?

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../documentos/games/banner.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\gameimage.php on line 11
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php5AD3.tmp' to '../documentos/games/banner.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\gameimage.php on line 11

**The code is:**

```
<?php if ((isset($_POST["enviado"])) && ($_POST["enviado"]=="form1")) { 
  $nome_arquivo = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "../documentos/games/".$nome_arquivo);
?>
  
<script>
  opener.document.fomr1.strImage.value = "<?php echo $nome_arquivo;?>";
  self.close();
</script>
 
<?php 
  } else {
?>
  
<form action="gameimage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
  <p>
    <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Upload Imagem" />
  </p>
  <input type="hidden" name="enviado" value="form1" />
</form>
    
<?php }?>
```

Comment: try using absolute paths, im not sure if `'../documentos/..'` will actually work

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES['userfile'])` to see if any errors are in the 'error' field. You should *always* check for that.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], __DIR__  . "/../documentos/games/".$nome_arquivo);`

Comment: @1337holiday using a full absolute path would become a pain when migrating the project.

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 thats true but by the looks of that code, i think migration is the least of his worries. He is mixing php in javascript :/

Comment: @1337holiday why shouldn't I mix php and javascrip?

Comment: its not good practice, what you are doing is called tight coupling. Think about what would happen if you were to change that variable name(`$nome_arquivo`) you would have to change it in 2 places. If you set ur system up right you will have less coding to do.

Comment: Hmm, I started learning php last month I don't know much, I appreciate the help, but what you told me to do didn't work, any other ideas? thks

Comment: @John Checkout Kohana ( http://kohanaframework.org/ ) or Code Igniter ( http://ellislab.com/codeigniter ) you are making a lot of mistakes that will be resolved by using a framework.  CI is probably easier to learn.